# make: *** No rule to make target 'node.o', needed by test-1-node. Stop

Tags: c++, makefile

Trying to run tests for coding project, keep getting error "make: *** No rule to make target 'node.o', needed by test-1-node. Stop..". All files are in the same directory so I'm not sure why it could be acting this way. If it makes a difference, node is a .hpp file. Also, teacher specifically forbids changing the makefile.
Here is the makefile:

```
tySHELL=/bin/bash
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -g -std=c++14 -Wall -Wall -Werror=return-type  \
            -Werror=uninitialized -Wno-sign-compare

SRCS = $(wildcard *.cpp)
HEADERS = $(wildcard *.hpp)
OBJECTS = $(SRCS:%.cpp=%.o)

CATCH = test/catch/catch.o
TEST_SRCS = $(wildcard test/*.cpp)
TESTS = $(TEST_SRCS:test/%.cpp=%)

main: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^

clean:
    $(RM) *.o *.gc* test/*.o test/*.gc* *.dSYM $(TESTS) main $(CATCH)

test-all: $(TESTS)

%.o: %.cpp $(HEADERS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

test-1-node: test/test-1-node.o node.o
test-2-filesystem-create: test/test-2-filesystem-create.o filesystem.o node.o
test-3-filesystem-move: test/test-3-filesystem-move.o filesystem.o node.o
test-4-filesystem-remove: test/test-4-filesystem-remove.o filesystem.o node.o

$(TESTS): $(CATCH)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^
    ./$@ --success

test-run: main
    echo -e "ls\ntouch foo\nmkdir bar\ntouch foo\ncd bar\ntouch baz\ncd ..\nls\nexit\n" | ./mainpe here
```

And here is the test-1-node:

```
#include "../node.hpp"
#include "catch/catch.hpp"

TEST_CASE("Node") {
  Node n("root", 'd');
  CHECK("root" == n.getName());
  CHECK('d' == n.getType());
  CHECK(nullptr == n.getParent());
  CHECK(0 == n.getChildren().size());

  Node* child = new Node("child", 'f');
  n.addChild(child);
  CHECK(child == n.getChild("child"));
  CHECK((&n == child->getParent()));

  n.addChild("second", 'd');
  CHECK('d' == n.getChild("second")->getType());

  Node* parent = new Node("parent", 'd');
  n.setParent(parent);
  CHECK(parent == n.getParent());

  CHECK(2 == n.getChildren().size());

  /* Verify removal of child and all successors */
  n.getChild("second")->addChild("seconds-new-baby", 'f');  // add grandchild
  n.removeChild("second");  // should remove second and seconds-new-baby
  CHECK(1 == n.getChildren().size());

  delete child;
  delete parent;
}
```

In console running "make main" then "make test-1-node" and getting error in title. Expect test to pass, or at least run but no such luck.

Comment: Looks like the makefile is expecting a node.cpp to exist somewhere. Yup. `test-1-node: test/test-1-node.o node.o` Odds are good the instructor didn't intend for you to completely implement node in a header.

Comment: Creating a simple `node.cpp` file that only contains `#include "node.hpp"` should resolve this.

Comment: But be careful. If the instructor expects to find node the node implementation in node.cpp and doesn't this may have a negative effect on the grading. Check with the instructor to prevent unfortunate surprises.